# saving last results in a text file

Tags: python

the problem i have is that i have a quiz which the user can pick from 3 classes. they then proceed to complete the quiz and currently their name and score is saved into a text file for the correct class (there are 3 different files for the 3 different classes). but how do i make it so if the same user has completed the quiz that only the last 2 scores that the student obtained is saved in the file rather than all of the scores.

```
if classChoice ==1:
        File=open("A.txt","a+")
        File.write(names+","+str(score)+"\n")
        File.close()

if classChoice ==2:
        File=open("B.txt","a+")
        File.write(names+","+str(score)+"\n")
        File.close()
if classChoice ==3:
        File=open("C.txt","a+")
        File.write(names+","+str(score)+"\n")
        File.close()
```

Comment: So you don't want to _append_ your score, but you want to _overwrite_ them?

Comment: @MrP01 um i dont want the previous scores of the other user whohve tken thequiz to be delete but  if the user has already done the quiz over 2 times thenthier odest score is delete

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you want to save your data in a specific data structure defined by yours. In your case you are interested in saving only last two scores of a specific student.

Let's observe how does your file "A.txt" look:

John,90

Sam,80

Alice,100

Sam,90

John,100

Instead of appending text each time, you have to read the whole file first, and convert it to something you can work with like dictionary.

```
def convert_file_to_dict(path):
  d = {}  
  lines = open(path).splitlines()
  for line in lines:
    name, grade = line.split(',')
    if name in d:
      d[name].append(grade)
    else:
      d[name] = [grade]
  return grade
```

In our case if I'll call `convert_file_to_dict('A.txt')`, I will receive dictionary which consists of `{ 'John':['90','100'], 'Sam':['80','90'], 'Alice':['100'] }`. Notice that the order in the list of grades is preserved by order of lines in "A.txt".

Now with that dictionary you can control that only last 2 grades are kept:

```
def insert_new_grade(grades_dict, name, grade):
  if name in grades_dict:
    if len(grades_dict[name]) == 1:
      grades_dict[name].append(str(grade))
    else:
      grades_dict[name] = grades_dict[name][1:] + [str(grade)]
  else:
    grades_dict[name] = [str(grade)]
```

Now all you need is to write a function which converts this dict to a file...
* You might want to use helpful objects like `collections.defaultdict`, but I didn't want to overkill here...

Comment: right. i shall tryand implemenet this into minebut dont think it will ork because i dont get how to to be honest. like do i put this in each if class statement

Comment: like which parts of the code do i actually need to add into my code for th scores to eb saved. as after i will have a function for teacher () who can choose the class to view and the scores are printed so i dont want the sores to be printed straight away after being written to the files

Comment: Please be more specific what your input is and what result do you want.